# Unique constraint violation found when creating a customer magento 2.3 after activating google captcha

Tags: captcha, google

''Unique constraint violation found'' when creating a customer in magento 2.3. The error appeared  after activating google captcha. Iam not sure if it may be related to the 50k spam accounts i had to delet. I deleted all spam accounts from the database but when creating a new account the ID does not start from 1.
Is there still anything left in the database  ?

[image: Unique constraint violation found when creating a customer magento 2.3 after activating google captcha]